# ¿Como mandar a imprimir a una impresora que no este establecida como predeterminada?

Tags: java

Hola estoy creando una aplicación en java en la cual mando imprimir gráficos a una impresora. El problema que tengo es que si no pongo la impresora como predeterminada en windows no manda imprimir a esa impresora.

He visto que a través del nombre se le manda a imprimir a la impresora, pero no se como implementarlo.

Este es mi código con el que imprimo actualmente:

```js
PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();

int numero = Integer.parseInt(SNumero.getValue().toString());

PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
aset.add(new Copies(numero));
aset.add(new MediaPrintableArea(0, 0, 62, 29, MediaPrintableArea.MM));
aset.add(Chromaticity.COLOR);
aset.add(OrientationRequested.PORTRAIT);
                


job.setPrintable(new ObjetoDeImpresion());
job.setJobName("nombre_de_impresion");

try {
  job.print(aset);
} catch (PrinterException ex) {
  System.out.println(ex);
}
```

Trato de mandarle el nombre de la impresora de la siguiente manera pero no funciona:

```js
String printerName = "Brother QL-800 (Copiar 1)";

aset.add(new PrinterName(printerName, null));
```

¿Alguien sabe como hacerlo?

Comment: Y si pruebas a obtener una lista de todas las impresoras disponibles y seleccionar la que deseas comparando el nombre con el de la impresora que quieres usar?

Comment: Pues también eso me funcionaria sabes como podría hacerlo @Jose?

Comment: Muestro mi respuesta sobre el mismo tema: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/301300/imprimir-texto-en-una-impresora-espec%C3%ADfica-java/ donde se puede ver como obtener las impresoras y seleccionas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí te dejo una función de ejemplo, que te devuelve un objeto de tipo PrintService introduciéndole un String con el nombre de la impresora que buscamos.

```
public PrintService impresora(String nombre){
    PrintService[] printServices = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null); //Obtenemos los servicios de impresion del sistema 
    for (PrintService impresora : printServices){ //Recorremos el array de servicios de impresion
        if(impresora.getName().contentEquals(nombre)){ // Si el nombre del servicio es el mismo que el que buscamos
            return impresora; // Nos devuelve el servicio 
        }
    }
    return null;    // Si no lo encuentra nos devuelve un null
}
```

Aqui te dejo varios enlaces a la documentacion de  [java acerca de los PrintService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jps/spec/printing.fm2.html#a998467)

Comment: Prueba cambiando el PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
por PrinterJob job =(PrinterJob) impresora("Brother QL-800 (Copiar 1)").createPrintJob();