# Imprimir texto en una impresora específica JAVA

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente fragmento de código que es completamente funcional e imprime correctamente el `ArrayList` que le paso con datos y siempre lo imprime en la impresora establecida por defecto.

```
try {

        PrintService p = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();

        DocPrintJob doc = p.createPrintJob();
        DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.BYTE_ARRAY.AUTOSENSE;
        Doc d = null;

        String textoTicket = "";

        for(int c=0; c<texto.size(); c++){

            textoTicket = textoTicket.concat(texto.get(c));

        }
        d = new SimpleDoc(textoTicket.getBytes(), flavor, null);
        doc.print(d, null);

    } catch (PrintException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se ha podido imprimir el ticket.", "Awsys", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
```

Mi pregunta es ¿como se puede hacer para elegir desde JAVA la impresora de destino entre todas las instaladas en el sistema?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: puedes agregar el codigo de la clase **DocPrintJob**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te dejo un ejemplo de como buscar una impresora por el nombre:

```
import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;
import javax.print.PrintService;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BuscadorImpresora {


    public PrintService buscar(String nombre) {

        PrintService service = null;

        // Obtienes el Array de impresoras disponibles 
        PrintService[] services = PrinterJob.lookupPrintServices();

        // Buscamos si el nombre de la impresora existe
        for (int i = 0; service == null && i < services.length; i++) {
            if (services[i].getName().indexOf(nombre) >= 0) {
                service = services[i];
            }
        }

        // Retornamos el servicio
        return service;
    }
```

Ejemplo de como seleccionar una impresora:

```
import javax.print.DocPrintJob;
import javax.print.PrintService;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;

public class Impresora {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Obtenemos la lista de las impresoras disponibles
        PrintService[] services = PrinterJob.lookupPrintServices();

        // Pedimos que ingresen el numero de la impresora
        int value = Integer.valueOf(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(formatPrinter(services)));

        // El valor obtenido especifica la posicion de la impresora
        PrintService print = services[value];

        // Mostramos las impresora seleccionada
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, String.format("La impresora seleccionada es: " + print.getName()), "Awsys", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        // Desde este punto utiliza el codigo que ya mostraste
        DocPrintJob doc = print.createPrintJob();
        //.......
    }

    public static String formatPrinter(PrintService[] services) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("Impresoras disponibles, seleccione una: ").append("\n");

        for (int i = 0; i < services.length; i++) {
            builder.append(i).append("- ").append(services[i].getName()).append("\n");
        }

        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Pero, ¿Como hago para decirle a java que utilice una impresora que yo quiera para imprimir algo? Gracias

Comment: Para eso debes utilizar es el array `PrintService[] services = PrinterJob.lookupPrintServices();` este array contiene las impresoras disponibles, te dejo un ejemplo simple de como solicitar el valor y seleccionar la impresora del array, por lo demás es utilizar lo que ya tienes.

Comment: He podido probarlo. La verdad que está genial pero hay un detalle que se me escapo decirte y es que yo tengo en un fichero de texto el nombre de la impresora que quiero usar. Es decir, en el momento que empieza tu codigo yo ya se en que impresora quiero imprimir y no hace falta elegirla. ¿Como podría hacer eso? Por cierto muchas gracias, eres un crack :P

Comment: Ya lo he conseguido tío. Muchisimas gracias, de verdad. Un saludo enorme!